# Add appsettings configuration DI to HostBuilder console app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, appsettings

I am trying to include an *appsettings.json* file in a .NET Core console app where I am using `HostBuilder`, and attempting to add a section (AppVars) to the configuration. When I try to do this, I get the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type AppVars while attempting to activate...

Here is my code:

```
private static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var isService = !(Debugger.IsAttached || args.Contains("--console"));

    var config1 = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
        .Build();

    var builder = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<FileWriterService>();

            services.Configure<AppVars>(config1.GetSection("AppVars"));

        });

    //...
}
```

And below I am trying to Inject AppVars in a class:

```
public class FileWriterService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private const string Path = @"d:\TestApplication.txt";

    private Timer _timer;
    private AppVars _appVars;
    public FileWriterService(AppVars appVars)
    {
       //_appVars = appVars;
    }


    //...

}
```

Comment: You're trying to inject a concrete implementation and not the interface

Comment: Even when I try to create an interface, IAppVars, it still gives the same error. I feel like i'm setting up something wrong in Main

Answer (score 7):

```
 services.Configure<AppVars>(config1.GetSection("AppVars"));
```

registers `IOptions<AppVars>` while the constructor is expecting just `AppVars`

Either update the target constructor accordingly so it expects the correct type

```
public class FileWriterService : IHostedService, IDisposable {
    private const string Path = @"d:\TestApplication.txt";

    private Timer _timer;
    private AppVars _appVars;
    public FileWriterService(IOptions<AppVars> appVars) {
       _appVars = appVars.Value;
    }

    //...

}
```

**Or**

leave the constructor as is, and refactor the startup to register the desired type

```
var builder = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) => {
        services.AddHostedService<FileWriterService>();
        AppVars appVars = hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("AppVars").Get<AppVars>();
        services.AddSingleton(appVars);

    });
```